# How to override a Symfony bundle config in a project

Tags: symfony

I have a Symfony bundle that has a predefined `security.yaml` config.

#### Bundle

The bundle has a `security.yaml` that defines some paths in access control:

```yaml
security:
    password_hashers:
        Bundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
    # ...
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/public, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

They are prepended to the config like this:

```php
class BundleExtension extends Extension implements PrependExtensionInterface
    public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        $yamlParser = new Parser();
        $securityConfig = $yamlParser->parse(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config/security.yml'));
        $container->prependExtensionConfig('security', $securityConfig['security']);
    }
}
```

#### Project

In the project i would like to append or change to the paths under `access_control`.

I tried adding this to `Kernel.php`:

```php
class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;

    protected function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);
        $container->addCompilerPass(new SecurityConfigCompilerPass());
    }
}
```

And in `SecurityConfigCompilerPass` I have this:

```
class SecurityConfigCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        $securityConfigs = $container->getExtensionConfig('security');

        foreach ($securityConfigs as $securityConfig) {
            if (array_key_exists('access_control', $securityConfig)) {
                $newConfig = $securityConfig;
                array_push($newConfig['access_control'], [
                    "path" => "^/",
                    "role" => "ROLE_ADMIN",
                ]);
            }
        }

        $securityExtension = $container->getExtension('security');
        $securityExtension->load($newConfig, $container);
    }
}
```

This then shows this error:

> Unrecognized option "Bundle\Entity\User" under "security". Available options are "access_control", "access_decision_manager", "access_denied_url", "enable_authenticator_manager", "erase_credentials", "firewalls", "hide_user_not_found", "password_hashers", "providers", "role_hierarchy", "session_fixation_strategy".

Not sure what it can't revolve the namespace `Bundle\Entity\User` anymore. Is there a better way to change the `access_control` paths?